# How to show Spec$\frac{\Bbb C [x, y]}{(xy)}$ is connected in the Zariski topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In exercise 3.6.E of Vakil's book, it is asked for the reader to find a ring for which its spec is connected and non-irreducible. Taking his hint, I  thought of $A = \frac{\Bbb C [x, y]}{(xy)}$. It is not irreducible, because $V((x)) \cup V((y)) = V((xy)) = \operatorname{Spec}A$. To prove connectedness I tried to use the fact that if $ \operatorname{Spec}A= V(I) \cup V(J) = V(IJ)$ where $V(I) \cap V(J) = \emptyset$ would imply $I + J = A$. Can anyone give me some hint?

Comment: If Spec(R) is disconnected, then there are orthogonal idempotents inside R ([wikipedia page on connected rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_ring#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20especially%20in%20the,topology%20is%20a%20connected%20space.)). If a polynomial $f$ satisfies $f(x,y)^2=f(x,y)$ in this ring, then what does this say about $f$?

Comment: A scheme is disconnected iff there exists a non-trivial idempotent global section. This should help you prove what you want. EDIT : Late comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments give you a completely algebraic way to view connectedness: a scheme $X$ is disconnected if and only if there exists $e\in\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ such that $e\neq 0,1$ and $e^2 = e.$ Proving that no such $e$ exists will do the trick.

Here's another method:

**Hint:** View $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb{C}[x,y]/(xy)$ as a closed subscheme of $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb{C}[x,y] = \Bbb{A}^2_\Bbb{C}$ (the particular subscheme structure doesn't matter since we're concerned about connectedness, which is a purely topological property). Recall that if $U_1, U_2\subseteq X$ are connected and $U_1\cap U_2\neq\emptyset,$ then $U_1\cup U_2$ is connected.